# Finding VMWare ESX host name from within a guest

Tags: vmware, esx

this question has been asked before several times, but never anyone brought up any reasonable solution.

? Is there any way, from within a Windows guest, to find the hostname or IP address of the ESX host ?

The scenario is as follows:

I am working on a virtual host (Windows 7 guest, I have Admin privileges on the guest, VMWare Tools are installed, I can install PowerCLI or any other tool if I want to [though I assume it wouldn't help]).

Now I need to contact the administrator of the underlying ESX server. If I can find out either the ESX server name, or the IP address, I can find out whom I must contact.

Is there any way from within the client to find either the ESX host name or its IP address?

Thx, Armin.

P.S. please don't - like many other postings do - suggest workarounds requiring that I do

a) set any info on the host side which I can later query from the client - cannot do this in my scenario, and to have anyone else do this I need to find the responsible person first.

b) say it cannot be technically done for some reason (including "sandbox" and "security") - I have VMware Tools installed, look at the "VMWareToolboxCmd.exe stat" command - it can retrieve various infos from the underlying host, like the clock time or the speed of the CPU, so there are ways to communicate with the host, but I failed to find any command to retrieve the host name or IP address.

c) use PowerCLI, VSphere client, etc. As far as I know all those approaches require that one knows the ESX hostname and has login credentials for the host, not the guest. I don't have login credentials for any ESX machine in the company.